# Javascript wrappers for Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am planning to build a JS based twitter client. Information about libraries/clients is pretty old on other SO Questions. I was wondering if anyone has come across wrappers other than Spaz and TwitterHelper.

Addition : Please note this will be client app which I also plan to run on mobiles using phonegap.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote an OAuth library for JavaScript that might help you. You can find it here:

http://bitbucket.org/techpriester/oauthentica.js

There's also some example documentation on how to extend it for use with Twitter:

http://bitbucket.org/techpriester/oauthentica.js/wiki/HowToExtend

Comment: This is certainly good stuff for the community, I will leave the question open for a day or two to possibly get more inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere), an official Twitter Javascript library. Full documentation [here](http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html).

Comment: I added a requirement to the question , sorry did not state it before. I kind of like @anywhere , but am not sure if I will be able to run on mobiles as I dont think I can give a variable callback url

Comment: what is the variable callback url for?

Comment: Its the URL twitter returns to after successfully authenticating, thus I cant use @anywhere to develop my app as users wont have a fixed callback :). I am still looking at possible workarounds for this

Comment: Update: maybe I need to sleep , its 6am here :D , but I competely missed a few options while registering my @anywhere app. I should be able to use it , will keep you updated :)